# How to get specific data from JSON file?

Tags: json, python-3.6

I am trying to get some data out of a JSON file using python 3.6

The JSON file looks like:

```
{
  "locations": [{
    "timestamp": *some real*
    "latitude": *some real*,
    "longitude": *some real*
  }, 
    ...
  }]
}
```

What I have tried is this:

```
import json

json_data = open("Location History.json")
data = json.load(json_data)

print(data[0]['locations'])
```

I am trying to get a list of all the latitudes, but I get an error saying `KeyError: 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
print(data[0]['locations'])
```

The key is "location" without an 's', change it to

```
print(data[0]['location'])
```